# C++ class definition

Tags: class

I've run across a class defined as follows:

```
class SYS_LIB_API Version
{
public:
somefunctions()
...
}
```

I don't understand the `class SYS_LIB_API Version` line. I'm used to seeing:

```
class Version
{
public:
somefunctions()
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its just a macro that the API creator uses to define certain this, many of them internal.

Comment: It's probably to allow adding the special declarations for compiling windows DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

SYS_LIB_API is undoubtedly a macro, but I couldn't tell you what it does unless I had access to the same code.